# SQL Server Set NOCOUNT on/off

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, nocount

To achieve better performance we use **Set NOCOUNT on** inside the SP?

Is it mandatory to mention **Set NOCOUNT off** at the end of the SP?

If not will it harm anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`set nocount on` will disable the X rows affected. message SQL returns. This message is suppressed, in some cases, due to undesired effects with the client executing the stored proc.

`set nocount off` will undo this suppression. However, set nocount on is a scope setting, and by default, will be turned off when leaving the scope anyway.

Now, is `set nocount off` necessary? No, as any new commands executed will be in a different scope, and by default `set nocount off` is always in effect. But as stated above in comments, it's considered a good practice, just to explicitly indicate that this setting will return to normal when the proc is finished executing.

Is it mandatory to mention `Set NOCOUNT off` at the end of the SP? - No

If not will it harm anywhere? - No